# CodeIgniter file path image resizing error

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

```
public function resize($image_data) {
   $img = substr($image_data['full_path'], 51);
   echo $img;
   $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
   $config['source_image'] = $image_data['full_path'];
   $config['new_image'] = '' . $img;
   $config['width'] = $this->input->post('width');
   $config['height'] = $this->input->post('height');
}
```

These lines of code produce the following file path:  `codeigniter.mainsitehere.com/manipulation_controller/0.com/uploads/name_of_image6.jpg`

(which is not where the file is stored)

The result I would like is:

```
codeigniter.mainsitehere.com/uploads/name_of_image6.jpg
```

or better yet

```
codeigniter.mainsitehere.com/uploads/6
```

Although this form will probably require a lot more fundemental changes to other parts of the site.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. I will also respond with more information/code if needed. 
**Edit:** 
This is the source I am using: https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-image-library/

And the question, if I had to put it in one sentence, is how do I manipulate this function and the PHP objects in it to create/display the correct filepath for a picture?